# PHP imagettftext() breaks the image if I use imagecreatefrompng, imagecreatefromjpeg and imagecreatefromgif

Tags: php, image, gd, wampserver, imagettftext

The image get loaded to the browser fine but when I try writing some text onto it, the image breaks (like this: http://www.tradenepal.com.np/test.php ). When I comment out imagettftext(), the image does not load again. This happening on my localhost and I use WampServer Version 2.5. I have gone through so many comments on the inetrnet but I can't seem to know what the problem is.  Any help would much be appreciated. Thank you. My code:

```
<?php 

//Set content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Create image from existing image
$jpgImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('file.jpg');

// Allocate color for text
$white = imagecolorallocate($jpgImage, 255, 255, 255);

// Set Path to Font File
$font = 'arialbd.ttf';

// Text to print to image
$text = 'Testing text output';

// Print Text On Image
imagettftext($jpgImage, 75, 0, 50, 400, $white, $font, $text);



// Send Image to Browser
imagejpeg($jpgImage);

// Clear Memory
imagedestroy($jpgImage);

?>
```

Comment: First check the image is large enough to place the test where you have positioned it. Second check that the `arialbd.ttf` file is correctly located where you have specified it.

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly, I figured it out later after asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Send Image to Browser

```
imagepng($jpg_image);  <------ remove image type png
```

// Output the image

```
imagejpeg($jpg_image);
```

I've tested, it works.

```
<?php
  //Set the Content Type
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

  // Create Image From Existing File
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('file.jpg');

  // Allocate A Color For The Text
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);

  // Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = 'arialbd.ttf';

  // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
  $text = "This is a sunset!";

  // Print Text On Image
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);

  // Send Image to Browser
  imagejpeg($jpg_image);

  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Buse Gönen. I made the corrected the mistake you pointed out but I also realised other mistakes so I have edited it but it's still not working. Can you please check again for me? Thanks.

Comment: my code, I have tested. working fine. No problem. Your change image.

Comment: Yeah. That's the problem. I don't know if it's a problem with my localhost. I have tried for 2 days now but it wouldn't work. Thanks anyway.